# Django-ORM instead of python for loop

Tags: django, performance, django-models, django-orm

**Hello Awesome People!**

Such a simple question, sometimes I used to loop through my models with the python for loop, this is not good for the performance of a website.

I have three 3 models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    Bs = ManyToManyField(B)

class B(models.Model):
    Cs = ManyToManyField(C)

class C(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
```

If I want to have all the instances of **C** model related to an instance of **A**, how will I proceed rather than this python for loop?

```
all_c = []
for b in a_instance.Bs.all():
    for c in b.Cs.all():
        all_c.append(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `prefetch_related` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

```
all_c = []
for b in a_instance.Bs.all().prefetch_related('Cs'):
    for c in b.Cs.all():
        all_c.append(c)
```

But better way will be just filtering on `C` model

```
all_c = C.objects.filter(b_set__a_set__in=[a_instance])
# or if you need it to be list and not queryset
all_c = list(C.objects.filter(b_set__a_set__in=[a_instance]))
```